# Stacking images one on another in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a website in which I am asked to add a certain animation and it all worked out great in plain HTML but when I uploaded it to Wordpress (which has the Salient theme installed on it, by the way) the image I wanted to animate didn't overlap the other one. Here's my code:

```css
.cdcase{
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
}


#case{
 position: relative; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 z-index:1;
}

#rotate {
 position: absolute;
 top: 30; 
 left: 30;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
  -moz-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -moz-transform 2s;
  -o-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -o-transform 2s;
}
    

#rotate:hover {
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
   z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="cdcase">
   <img id="case" src="http://firmebucuresti.net/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/case.png" >
   <a href="#"><img id ="rotate" src="http://firmebucuresti.net/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/cd.png" alt="cd"></a>
</div>
```

The CD should be under the blue "case" but as a matter of fact, now that I uploaded the animation via the code snippet I noticed that it doesn't work here either but on my localhost it does. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You done everything well! But you need move z-index from `#rotate:hover` to `#rotate`, like this:

```css
.cdcase{
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
}


#case{
 position: relative; 
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 z-index:1;
}

#rotate {
 position: absolute;
 top: 30; 
 left: 30;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, transform 2s;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
  -moz-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -moz-transform 2s;
  -o-transition: width 2s, height 2s, -o-transform 2s;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 220px;
}
    

#rotate:hover {
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cdcase">
   <img id="case" src="http://firmebucuresti.net/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/case.png" >
   <a href="#"><img id ="rotate" src="http://firmebucuresti.net/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/cd.png" alt="cd"></a>
</div>
```

Also, you need set some left/right/top/bottom value to make margin from the left-top corner of the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. It works like a charm in the snippet editor here on the site now but it doesn't seems to work on the wordpress theme I'm working on. It is exactly the same code as you posted it yet it doesn't seem to do the trick. I think I may have to edit the core stylesheet of the theme but I don't know how or where... Thanks again, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D It actually helped, I only forgot to add the [code]-ms-[/code] vendor prefix. I owe you my life

Comment: @Daniel glad to help you!